# randomly distributing labels in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to randomly distribute a number of labels on a view. The code below works but obviously the distribution isn't very random, therefore I substituted in this line

```
cat.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - ( 50 * arc4random() % self.numOfCats), (50 * arc4random() % self.numOfCats), 100, 100);
```

to try to at least create some semblance of randomness, however, none of the labels appeared on the screen and there were no error messages.  Can you explain why?

**Bonus**
I don't think the method of creating randomness is that great either (i.e. unlikely to ever get any at 0,0), Bonus,can you improve the method of creating randomness too? I have to ensure that none of the labels are overlapping too...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= self.numOfCats; i++) {
    Cat *cat = [self timer];
    cat.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 500 , 100 * i, 100, 100);         
    [self.view addSubview:cat];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea of a better approach to a random position of your label:

```
CGRect newFrame = cat.frame; //The original frame, whichever it was considering size
//Consider the width of the cat to avoid placing it outside of the screen
newFrame.origin.x = [self randomFloatBetweenLowerLimit:0
                                            upperLimit:CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(cat.frame)]; 

//Consider the width of the cat to avoid placing it outside of the screen
newFrame.origin.y = [self randomFloatBetweenLowerLimit:0
                                            upperLimit:CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(cat.frame)];
cat.frame = newFrame;
```

This would be the method to get the random float, considering modulo bias:

```
- (CGFloat)randomFloatBetweenLowerLimit:(CGFloat)lowerLimit
                             upperLimit:(CGFloat)upperLimit
{
    return arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX) / (CGFloat)UINT32_MAX * (upperLimit - lowerLimit) + lowerLimit;
}
```

Comment: To avoid "modulo bias" you should use `arc4random_uniform((int)CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame.size.width))`

Comment: This code `CGRectFrame newFrame;` is giving me an error `use of undeclared Identifer CGRectFrame did you mean UIRectFrame`  same result if I do `CGRectFrame newFrame = cat.frame;`  can you explain?

Comment: @lucianomarisi thanks, there's one more error in the 2nd and 3rd lines: `passing CGFloat (aka float) to parameter of incompatible type CGRect`  is there an easy fix?

Comment: Sorry again, fired up Xcode and fixed it properly, originally I wrote the code of the top of my head, things should work now.

Comment: @lucianomarisi Thanks for your help one small problem, some of the labels aren't visible (on some occasions) and/or that only part of the label is on screen (right at the edge) Is it possible that the some of the labels are hidden under other labels or that the coordinates are getting set outside boundary? I'm viewing this on a simulator

Comment: fixed the boundary problem by doing this ` int width = self.view.frame.size.width - 30;
            int height = self.view.frame.size.height - 30;
            newFrame.origin.x = arc4random() % width;
            newFrame.origin.y = arc4random() % height;`

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing, i.e. consider the size of the label, anyways I've updated the answer to account for the whole of this discussion.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, to not have overlapping labels, you would have to compare the rect of the proposed label to all the ones you currently have on screen. I answered a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875806/fill-view-with-buttons-at-random-positions/22877435#22877435.